# PHP if does not equal to or another does not equal to

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to do a conditional if statement that checks whether the value of a variable **$cat_ID** is not equal to **19** or **26** then it should echo my **$priceToShow** variable.

**PHP**

```
if(($cat_id != '19') || ($cat_id !='26')){ 
    echo $priceToShow;
}
```

Comment: So. What's the question?

Comment: Where's the problem? What you have looks good.

Comment: guy is just showing little bit of his code here. give him a break :D

Comment: $cat_id!=19 as value OR $cat_id!='19' as string?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If it can be neither 19 nor 26, use an and statement:

```
if(($cat_ID != '19') && ($cat_id !='26')){ 
    echo $priceToShow;
}
```

If you have a lot of values to check, use `in_array`:

```
$bad_values = array(19, 26, 54);
if (!in_array($cat_ID, $bad_values)) {
    echo $priceToShow;
}
```

(In this case, strict comparisons are off; you should always cast your data to the type it's expected to be, and then use strict comparison:

```
$bad_values = array(19, 26, 54);
if (!in_array(intval($cat_ID), $bad_values, true)) {
    echo $priceToShow;
}
```

)

Comment: variable names are also case sensitive  :)

Comment: @splash21 Oh, they are.

Answer (score 7):

This will always return true

You need to use an AND conjunction

of for more than 2 values use ! in_array()

Edit: Absolutely right @Waygood

```
if ( ! ( $v == 19 || $v == 26 ) ) {
  // do your thing
}
```

Comment: demorgans theorum: negate and change operator = OR to != AND e.g. 19 OR 26 -> !=19 AND !=26 http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_4/chpt_7/8.html

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to use `!in_array()`. That'll make it quicker and simpler to add and remove when/if needed

```
if (!in_array($cat_id, array('19', '26')))
{
  echo $priceToShow;
}
```